# SceneKit – How to rotate a light?

Tags: swift, scenekit, virtual-reality

I am learning SceneKit. And I have a simple scene with a single shape and a light.

Here is the light code:

```
let lightNode = SCNNode()
lightNode.light = SCNLight()
lightNode.light?.castsShadow = true
lightNode.light?.type = .directional
lightNode.light?.intensity = 1000
lightNode.position = SCNVector3(x: -6, y: 0, z: 30)
lightNode.rotation = SCNVector4(x: 0, y: 0, z: 1.0, w: 3.14 / 2)
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(lightNode)
```

It produces the following result:
[image]

When I comment/uncomment lightNode.rotation the result remains the same. However I expect, that this circle highlight at the center of the shape changes or disappears.

Answer (score 0):

You are rotating the directional light around the `z-axis` and it will have no effect, because your light source is directed along the `-Z` axis by default. Try rotating your Sun light source around the `x-axis` or `y-axis`.

```
lightNode.rotation = SCNVector4(x: 1, y: 0, z: 0, w: -.pi / 15)
```

P. S.

There is no sense in using `.position` for `Sun light`. For this type of light, only orientation matters.